# Is this dual-spaced norm based on $L_2$ norm

Tags: finite-groups, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, duality-theorems

I am reading the book of Claes Johnson about *Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations by the Finite Element Method* and particularly pages 34 and 98.

I wrote these notes to my craft

[image]

**Is the equation (87) really so-called dual space norm $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ of $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$?**

I need a function $v \in L_2(I)$ that is a piecewise continuous and bounded.
**How can you write it to this definition?**
It cannot be to *possibly unbounded*, as was originally in *Johnson*, in my case for ECG signal.